# Split a string only two times

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like `abc~def~ghij~klm~nop~qrstu~vwx~hj`. I want to split it only two times (to three parts as the result): that means wherever I get `~` symbol I need to split `abc`, `def` and third as a single string only `ghij~klm~nop~qrstu~vwx~hj`.

I know how to split into strings wherever `~` symbol comes

```
String[] parts = stat.split("~");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3 = parts[2];
```

Here I get only part3 as `ghij`, I need the whole string remaining long with `~` symbol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This splits the `stat` String only two times, i.e. it splits it in 3 parts:

```
String[] parts = stat.split("~", 3);
```

[`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) method allows for control over the number of resulting parts.

Quoting the Javadoc:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.

Comment: I think this is the best method..let me check

Comment: But how I will get the third part...I am getting the second part as third string

Comment: @Jocheved Really? These approach (also Gala's and Ravi's) should be work. [sample](https://ideone.com/jhGagJ)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

```
String[] parts = stat.split("~", 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

use limit to split().

```
String s="abc~def~ghij~klm~nop~qrstu~vwx~hj";
String[] parts = s.split("~",3);
System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
System.out.println(parts[2]);
```