# Java SPLIT with colon : and xml

Tags: java, xml, split, tokenize

I have to split key values using **:** but the problem is that the value is an XML.

```
("User1":"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><presence xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf\" xmlns:dm=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model\" xmlns:rpid=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid\" xmlns:c=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:cipid\" entity=\"ivaxer@tipmeet.com\"></presence>")
```

What I want is a map with key as User1 and value as XML.

I tried `input.split(":");` and this doesn't work as it splits everything in the xml namespaces. I tried `input.split("\\\":\"");` this doesn't do anything.

Maybe some regex can help but I am not getting what exactly it could be.

Comment: Something like this, which splits only 2 times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349245/split-a-string-only-two-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your key does not contain colons, you can try the following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "\"User1\":\"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><presence xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf\" xmlns:dm=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model\" xmlns:rpid=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid\" xmlns:c=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:cipid\" entity=\"ivaxer@tipmeet.com\"></presence>";
    final int firstIndexOfColon = str.indexOf(':');
    if(firstIndexOfColon >= 0) {
        final String key = str.substring(0, firstIndexOfColon);
        final String val = ((firstIndexOfColon + 1) < str.length()) ? str.substring(1 + firstIndexOfColon) : "Empty value string";
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(val);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No delimiter found");
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to specify the syntax more precisely, so a regex can be prepared.

Comment: Awesome. simple solution.